# Type of Databases on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to look at catalog data to determine if the database is an Azure SQL Data Warehouse Database?

For example, I have an initial database I've created via Azure, however I've found I can create another database in this Azure SQL Data Warehouse database without specifying EDITION or SERVICE_OBJECTIVE.

I'm assuming this is a logical Azure SQL Database like master, but it is not a system database so I'd like to be able to determine the "type" of database I am connecting to.  So far I've just thought about looking to see if particular pdw_ views exist however I'm thinking there is probably a better way.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** The below suggestion works at the time of the post. This behavior is subject to change in the future.

There is not a straightforward way to do this today. I've added a feature request for a way to discover the service objective via TSQL. As a shortcut, you can run the following command:

```
SELECT
    name,
    recovery_model,
    recovery_model_desc
FROM
    sys.databases
WHERE
    name = DB_NAME();
```

If the recovery_model = 3 (SIMPLE), this is a SQL Data Warehouse database. If recovery_model = 1 (FULL), this is a SQL database.

**Update May 2016:**

The following query will return DataWarehouse if you are connected to an Azure SQL DW database:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Edition') As Edition
```

**Update #2:**
You can query the [sys.database_service_objectives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712619.aspx) DMV to get this information:

```
SELECT
 db.[name] AS [Name],
 ds.[edition] AS [Edition],
 ds.[service_objective] AS [ServiceObject]
FROM
 sys.database_service_objectives ds
 JOIN sys.databases db ON ds.database_id = db.database_id
```

Comment: Just be aware if you are connected to the `master` database on your Azure SQL Data Warehouse server, this will return `System` instead of `DataWarehouse`.